# Does SSAS faster if using InMemory Table SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, ssas-tabular

I want to change my tables into InMemory table, and also I created SSAS from that table.
wheather OLAP could be faster if I change into InMemory tables ?
Please advice.

I am concern about my memory.
I am using SQL 2014 and SSAS Tabular

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your SSAS is not in [DirectQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230898(v=sql.120).aspx) mode, I don't think it will get any faster since when processed it creates a copy of the data in the table.

I also don't think the processing will get any faster if you are selecting de whole table into a SSAS tabular table.

Anyway, the best approach here it's to test before/after in your Test enviroment.

Comment: No I am not in DirectQueryMode, so it doesn't change much

Comment: If you are interested in improving your processing time, you may test it but I don't think it'll get any better.
If SSAS and the DB are on the same server, you could experiment memory pressure. But all that has to be tested.

Comment: It is worth testing your SQL table as a clustered columnstore. Since the compression is typically 10x or so it usually improves processing time of a cube. I figured you didn't mean columnstore when you said InMemory